# Xamarin.Forms Entry.Height is bigger than Label.Height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid-layout

I have a Xamarin.Forms grid that I'm setting up and I've noticed that the `Entry` fields are a lot higher (3 - 4 times) than label fields. I can't see any obvious reason why this would be the case.

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="G/C" FontSize="Small"/>
    <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

This results in something like this (on the default Android Emulator, installed 2 days ago);
[image: Entry Example]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the Entry height is so much bigger and what I can do to reduce it (obviously HeightRequest, but I'd rather avoid if possible)?

Comment: Not enough reputation point to comment , so posting it as an answer. I also faced same issue and i solved it by setting **HeightRequest** property in Entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments here is a suggestion to do what you want in XAML. You can bind `Entry.HeightRequest` to `Label.Height` to avoid setting it manually.

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="G/C" FontSize="Small" x:Name="MyLabel" />
    <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyLabel}, Path=Height}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Of course! Simple and effective. Does exactly what I'm after, though I now realise the text doesn't show because the height is too small, typical! The label needs some padding anyway, I'm sure I can figure it out from here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Star` (`*`) as the height for the rows, this will make all rows have the same height. `Auto` will set the rows to a height that the control is just fitting in.

Comment: So, the Entry control is actually larger than a label? Seems a little odd. I don't think I can use * because this grid is going to be larger than the screen and sit inside a scrollview, if I use * the rows would end up too small wouldn't they?

Comment: @Trent It depends. When you set the `VerticalOptions` of the grid to `Fill`, I believe that the grid will be compressed to fit the parent, but when using `FillAndExpand` it should trigger the scrolling and take the place needed for its controls.

Comment: Hrmm, using the above definition I added `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` to the Grid tag and set both rows to `*`. Now takes up the entire height of the screen. Just `Fill` also does the same. Thoughts? Maybe I do have to use HeightRequest. I'm just wary about how that will work with different sized screens; I'm intending for this app to work on the majority of devices...

Comment: @Trent Try with `StartAndExpand` - this should do better. XF layouts are hairy beasts ;)

Comment: Hah, so I see. We're getting closer; Label is now as big as the Entry...

Comment: Played around a bit with the VerticalOptions, can't seem to get anywhere. Might have to resort to HeightRequest unless you have any other ideas @Paul Kertscher

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the current issue is. Didn't you write that label and entry have the same height now?

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry. Wrong way around though. The label expanded to the same size as the entry, I'm trying to reduce my space usage.

Comment: Ah, okay, then I misunderstood the whole issue from the beginning. I just thought that you wanted them the *same* size.